# user_Id Session Secure ? Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

In Hartl's tutorial we set the session as a cookie stored as a hashed version of the user_id. We then compare the unhashed cookie to a user.id

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out

```
def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

Is this secure?  Couldn't I session hash random user_id numbers to generate a cookie myself that I could then use to log in as another random user?

Comment: Hartl's book is just for tutorial and you are able to customize it in what securty you want.

Comment: so it's unsecure and my explanation for why is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of rails the data stored by the cookie store is either cryptographically signed (users can see all the data, but modifications are detected and rejected) or signed and encrypted (modifications are still rejected, but users can't what you're storing in the session). In both cases if you tamper with the session data you'll get an exception when rails tries to load the session.

You can use these protections for regular cookies to, by using `cookies.signed` or `cookies.encrypted` in your controller.

The key used for the encryption/signing is derived from the `secret_key_base` setting (in recent versions of rails, this is in config/secrets.yml). If an attacker were have access to this setting then they could forge cookie store session data.

Comment: So, the secret_key_base is unique per rails application.  If I create two different rails apps, I can expect two different secret_key_base encryption "codes". Additionally, in the example no one knows that I'm hashing the user:id, except me.  Compromising the database wouldn't give a malicious user knowledge of the secret_key_base or my technique for utilizing the session.  Although, if the database is compromised and there isn't a hashed session column, they might be able to infer my session hashing technique.  Do you think that's a correct interpretation of your answer?

Comment: It is indeed unique. I wouldn't worry about keeping how you use the session secret - that's just security through obscurity , which isn't worth much. The database doesn't really come into this much.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't want to expose user.id. The way that sessions work is that session[:user_id] will create a temporary cookie and will automatically encrypt the user.id. It's one of the differences between session[:user_id] vs cookie[:user_id]. It will then decrypt automatically on the next page. So technically it is still considered secure.

Comment: It's secure in the sense that I'm hashing a number,  but since the base number is non random and easily guessable, wouldn't we consider it non secure?  We know the :user_id starts at 1 and increments.